# Type conversion. What do I do with a PostgreSQL OID value in libpq in C?

Tags: c, postgresql, libpq

I'm working with the PostgreSQL C API, libpq. I need to be able to convert the values in a `PGresult*` into their equivalent data types in Ruby. I'm currently just selecting all the data and using `PQgetvalue()`, which gives me a `char*` that I can convert into a ruby String. That's easy. But are there any examples somebody can share that do a type conversion from the `char*` to, say, `int`, `float` or `double`, according to the OID returned by `PQftype()`?

Actually, in short I have no idea how to interpret the OID and [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-exec.html) doesn't seem to give any pointers. I found [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-oid.html), but that doesn't help understand how to use this OID to do a type conversion in the C API. I'm guessing there's a list of constants somewhere I can make a big switch statement from?

Answer (score 15):

I found the answer after asking this. Basically there's a file called catalog/pg_type.h, alongside libpq-fe.h and postgres.h. You need to include after including libpq-fe.h and postgres.h, then you can access the definitions like `TEXTOID`, `BOOLOID`, `INT4OID` etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <postgres.h>
#include <libpq-fe.h>
#include <catalog/pg_type.h>

// ... snip ...

if (PQgetisnull(result, row, col)) {
  // value is NULL, nothing more to do
} else {
  char * value  = PQgetvalue(result, row, col);
  int    length = PQgetlength(result, row, col);

  switch (PQftype(result, col)) {
    case INT2OID:
    case INT4OID:
    case INT8OID:
      // process value as an integer
      break;

    default:
      // just default to a text representation
  }
}
```

You need to look at all the OIDs in pg_type.h to actually have an extensive list, or just test what you get back doing basic `SELECT 't'::boolean` type queries etc and build up the switch only as you need a new type supporting.

Comment: These headers are part of the postgres server code rather than the libpq client code. Do the values change between postgres releases?

Answer (score 4):

To get the type name from an OID, just cast it to [`regtype`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html):

```
SELECT  700::oid::regtype -- real
```

To get the type of any columns (or variable in plpgsql), use [`pg_typeof()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE):

```
SELECT  pg_typeof(1::real) -- real
```

Gives you an answer of type `regtype` which is `displayed` as `text` in psql or pgAdmin. You can cast it to `text` explicitly if needed:

```
SELECT  pg_typeof(1::real)::text -- real
```

There is also this "big list", vulgo catalog table `pg_type`, where types are registered. This can be big, have a peek:

```
SELECT * from pg_type LIMIT 10;
```

[More info in the excellent manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-type.html)

Comment: Thanks, though do you know if there's a way to get this from the C API instead of round-tripping to the server for every column in every result? I'm only interested in core types, not user types.

Comment: You can have Postgres send this information with every result, just add SELECT items - though it would be redundant (per row). I am not familiar with the C API.

Comment: No dramas. Thanks for your help. I'm implementing a client library, so would prefer not to modify user queries, or send excessive additional requests to the server. I think I have found it now, actually, in catalog/pg_type.h :)

Comment: @d11wtq: Cool. No surprise abut the name, huh? :)