# Is it safe to use fundamental type OID defined in catalog header on client code?

Tags: postgresql, compatibility

This [QA entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530449/type-conversion-what-do-i-do-with-a-postgresql-oid-value-in-libpq-in-c/12531823#comment30472098_12531823) shows how to get OID code from catalog header.

It might be the simplest way to get OID numbers. Anyway the header file itself is explicitly separated from client-side header, so it seems it implies not to be used on client side.

Is it safe to use these server-side constants on client side? It's predictable that it will make some legacy issue. Older version of server may lack specific OID code. So I ask excluding this case. I mean, can I assume *once define OID code *for fundamental types* to be same eternally on future versions*?

**Update**

I meant only for *fundamental types*. Such as `TEXTOID`, `INT8OID` or `TIMESTAMPOID`. No custom, composite, user-defined or any other non-fundamental stuffs.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on it.  OIDs in pretty much every other case are per-server or per-database, so counting on them to be universally constant -- even if they explicitly are for that case, which i don't know -- would give me the willies.

Comment: @cHao Ah, your comment reminded me that I forgot one point - that this question was about fundamental types. How do you think about only for fundamental types?

Comment: It's still an implementation detail.  If you can't find a list of type OIDs in the manual or something, and have to go rooting around in the source code to find them, you're already doing something dodgy in order to need them IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, [this is the best I could find](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTimiNjQa7ws1tyR_W6RQPec6RlxQtWfACNMnZ_1P@mail.gmail.com). I would go with hardcoding OIDs.

Cited from Merlin Moncure's mention from the mailing list entry.

> built in type oids are defined in pg_type.h: cat
>   src/include/catalog/pg_type.h | grep OID | grep define
>
> built in type oids don't change. you can pretty much copy/pasto the
>   output of above into an app...just watch out for some types that may
>   not be in older versions.
>
> user defined type oids (tables, views, composite types, enums, and
>   domains) have an oid generated when it is created.  since that oid can
>   change via ddl so you should look it up by name at appropriate times.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe to use these server-side constants on client side? (...) I mean, can I assume once define OID code to be same eternally on future versions?

I honestly doubt it's not safe. The oids will likely be different depending on the Postgres version that was initially installed when new types etc are introduced. Older installs that get upgraded may or may not have the same oids as the same on fresh installs.

For illustration purposes, picture yourself creating an admin user with ID 1 in an app when it gets installed, and hard-coding everything in C by defining ADMIN_USER as that ID. Your customers then add new users, etc. In a subsequent release, you add a quasi-admin user with ID 2 and proceed tohard-code everything around that too. Customers upgrade... and, well, it blows up in your face because on their end, the quasi-admin user can have any ID...

When you use hard-coded oids in Postgres, the same kind of thing may happen. In one version, the built-in types are created in a certain order; in the next, they may be created in another because e.g. Postgres adds a shiny new `enum` or `int4range` type. And this doesn't begin to touch the topic of what may potentially occur during upgrades. (Admittedly, dumping and reloading data should yield sane things here, but I wouldn't take the chance myself.)